# where do spyware commonly reside

Tags: spyware

where do spyware commonly stay on your computer. what locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System32, and your personal directories (i.e. `Documents and Settings\you\*`)

But really they can be anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Spyware on windows has no reason to be in a specific file, apart from maybe in a directory in your path variable. Though really it wouldn't matter where it was, so it could just make a directory where ever it wanted and do what it wanted from there. 
I agree to use an application, since these are especially designed and usually invest a lot of money to make ways to locate them. Even if you do delete a folder it's in, it may have spawned lots of files with copies in or changed the registry which would be very difficult to manually find problems in

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere. If they stuck to certain locations, they'd be easy to find and remove. Many even randomly generate a location on each computer - it might be `C:\Windows\apweorpu.exe` on one computer, and `C:\Windows\System\qpoxzweor.exe` on another.

Don't rely on manually hunting them down on the filesystem. Use the spyware detection apps out there - and more than one, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

*IF* there were a specific location where spyware lives, anti-spyware software would easily be able to prevent and remove it.  Instead, spyware tends to *replace* existing files at various places in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you don't look.

(Use a system scanner, or reformat to be sure...)